# Never ending 'for' loop prevents my RStudio notebook from being rendered into a .md file

Tags: for-loop, rstudio

I'm trying to calculate the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic in R. I have the following sample, which clearly comes from a random variable that follows a long-tailed distribution.

> Download link
>
> > https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hIgqikX7p343zdyc-Goq34THUpsZA63n/view?usp=sharing

As you may know, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic requires the calculation of the empirical cumulative distribution function and the presumed cumulative distribution function. For both calculations I take the following approach: first, I create a vector with the same length as the length of the sample, and **then I modify each of the components of the vector so as for it to contain the empirical cdf (or presumed cdf) of the corresponding observation of the sample**.

For the sake of illustration, I'll show you the code I wrote in order to calculate the empirical cdf.

> I'm assuming that the data has been read and stored in a dataframe called data.
>
> > ecdf = vector("numeric", length(data$logueos))
> >
> > for (i in 1:length(data$logueos)) {
> >
> > ecdf[i] = sum (data$logueos <= data$logueos[i])/length(data$logueos)
> >
> > }

The code I wrote for the calculation of the presumed cdf is analogous to the preceding one; the only difference is that I set each component of the pcdf vector equal to the formula $P(X<=t)$ —where t is the corresponding observation of the sample— according to the distribution that I'm assuming.

**The problem is that this 'for' loop never ends.** If I force it to end by clicking RStudio's stop button it works: it makes the vector store what I want it to store. But, if I press Ctrl+Shift+k in order to render my notebook and preview it, the load gets stuck when trying to execute the first chunk encountered that contains one of those loops.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **your loop is not endless.** It will finish, eventually.

You start initializing a vector with as much elements as the number of observations (1.245.888, which is a lot of iterations). **This vector is FULL OF ZEROS**.

What your loop does is iterate while changing each zero with the calculus `sum (data$logueos <= data$logueos[i])/length(data$logueos)`. Check that when you stop the execution, the first values of your vector will be values between 0 and 1 while the last values is going to be 0s (because the loop hasn't arrived there yet). 
So, you will have to wait more time.

In order to make the execution faster, you could consider **loop parallelization** (because standard loops go sequentially, one by one, and if it's too much wait, parallelization makes it faster. For example, executing 4 by 4, depending of your computer capacities). Here you'll find some information about it: https://nceas.github.io/oss-lessons/parallel-computing-in-r/parallel-computing-in-r.html

Then, my proposal to you:

```
if(!require(foreach)){install.packages("foreach")}; require(foreach)
registerDoParallel(detectCores() - 1)

ecdf = vector("numeric", length(data$logueos))

foreach (i=1:length(data$logueos)) %do% {
  print(i)
  ecdf[i] = sum (data$logueos <= data$logueos[i])/length(data$logueos)
}
```

- The first line will download and load `foreach` library, that you
  need for parallelization.
- `detectCores() - 1` is going to use all the
  processors that your computer has except one (to avoid freezing your
  machine) for computing this loop. You'll see that is going to be
  faster!
- `registerDoParallel` function is what tells to `foreach` how many cores use.